# Detect element is at the top of its parent - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm triyng to build a simple content scroller.

On my utton click I move a div up and down 15 pixels of its parent, If its at the top however id like to disable this function, whats the best way to do this?...

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/dwkurpjm/

**jQUERY**

```
$('.up').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().prev().find('.inner-scroll').css({
        marginTop: '-=15px'
    });
});
$('.down').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().prev().find('.inner-scroll').css({
        marginTop: '+=15px'
    });
});
```

Comment: don't add if margin value is `>=0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using margin why don't you use `scrollTop` property? This is the property which should be used to change the scrolling state.

The browser will take care to not let the values go less than 0 or beyond the upper bound.

```
 $('.up').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = $(this).parent().prev();
        s.scrollTop(s.scrollTop()-15);
    });
    $('.down').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = $(this).parent().prev();
        s.scrollTop(s.scrollTop()+15);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwkurpjm/2/

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the height of your inner-scroll div before moving like below so that whenever the top offset exceeds parent div offset it stops moving.

```
if($(".inner-scroll").offset().top>$('.scroll').offset().top){
//execute your code
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/kubuwuyolaha/1/edit)